# How to remove create button in listview SugarCrm 7

Tags: sugarcrm

How to remove create button in ListView in SugarCRM 7.

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? Post sample of code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an API for it : IN `custom/clients/base/api` but this will hide create button from every where for that module.

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Harshal
 */
/*
 * Your installation or use of this SugarCRM file is subject to the applicable
 * terms available at
 * http://support.sugarcrm.com/06_Customer_Center/10_Master_Subscription_Agreements/.
 * If you do not agree to all of the applicable terms or do not have the
 * authority to bind the entity as an authorized representative, then do not
 * install or use this SugarCRM file.
 *
 * Copyright (C) SugarCRM Inc. All rights reserved.
 */

if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry)
    die('Not A Valid Entry Point');
require_once("clients/base/api/CurrentUserApi.php");

class CustomCurrentUserApi extends CurrentUserApi {

    public function registerApiRest() {
        return parent::registerApiRest();
    }

    public function retrieveCurrentUser($api, $args) {
        $result = parent::retrieveCurrentUser($api, $args);

        $result['current_user']['acl']['MODULENAME']['create'] =

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your view.list.php:

```
public function getModuleTitle($show_help = true)
{
    parent::getModuleTitle(false);
}
```